# CSS styling divs and paragraphs

Tags: html, css, height

I have a page wich gives me two problems when I try to style it using CSS. First the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="formarea">

    <div class="formimg">Du själv:</div>

    <div class="formtext">

        <p class="inhead">Personuppgifter:</p>

        <p class="tdone" id="namespan">Namn</p>     <p class="tdtwo"><input type="text" name="graduate[name]" id="name" /></p>
        <p class="tdone" id="addrspan">Adress</p>       <p class="tdtwo"><input type="text" name="graduate[address]" id="address" /></p>
        <p class="tdone" id="postspan">Postadress</p>   <p class="tdtwo"><input type="text" name="graduate[postal]" id="postal" /></p>
        <p class="tdone" id="mailspan">E-post</p>       <p class="tdtwo"><input type="text" name="graduate[email]" id="email" /></p>
        <p class="tdone" id="phonspan">Mobilnummer</p>  <p class="tdtwo"><input type="text" name="graduate[phone]" id="phone" /></p>
        <p class="tdone" id="pnrspan">Personnummer</p>  <p class="tdtwo"><input type="text" name="graduate[pnr]" id="pnr" /></p>

        <p class="inhead">Matalternativ:</p>            

        <p class="tdone">Vegetarian (vegan etc. fyll även i detta nedan)</p><p class="tdtwo"><input type="checkbox" name="graduate[veg]" value="Ja" /></p>
        <p class="tdone">Allergier och andra matpreferenser</p><p class="tdtwo"><textarea name="graduate[allergies]" id="allergies"></textarea></p>

        <p class="inhead">Alkoholalternativ:</p>

        <p class="tdone">Öl</p><p class="tdtwo"><input type="radio" name="graduate[drink]" value="Öl" checked /></p>
        <p class="tdone">Cider</p><p class="tdtwo"><input type="radio" name="graduate[drink]" value="Cider" /></p>
        <p class="tdone">Alkoholfritt</p><p class="tdtwo"><input type="checkbox" name="graduate[alcfree]" value="Ja" /></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:
    body {
    }

```
.formarea {
    margin:auto;
    margin-top:25px;
    padding:0px;
    border:none;
    width:364px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
}

.formimg {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding:0px;    
    border:none;
    width:45px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#dddddd;
}

.formtext {
    margin-top:-45px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:64px;
    padding:0px;
    border:none;
    width:300px;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    background-color:#cccccc;
}

.inhead {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding:0px;
    border:none;
    width:300px;
    font-size:20px;
}

.tdone {
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding:0px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}

.tdtwo {
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding:0px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
}

.tdtwo input {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;  
    width:150px;
}

.tdtwo textarea {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    width:150px;
}
```

Here is a picture if the result:

[image: Result of css]

As you can see, the code works fine down to "Matalternativ:", but then something strange happens. I have managed to figure out that the reason for this is because the text needs two roads. The simple (but very ugly) solution is to ingrease the height of ".tdone" and ".tdtwo" to a number above the height of two lines, but it is not very good.

I also tried toying with the overflow property, but that didn't seem to help me.

This makes two questions:

1: There are reasons for not wanting an id because that won't help me later in parts of the code not shown here where the same problem will appear. Is there a css property that will help me when a line is too high other than putting an id on that particular element?

2: As you can see, the radiobuttons and checkboxes align in the center of the paragraph they populate. I have tried "text-align:left;" and "Float:left;" inside ".tdtwo input" which didn't make any difference. Is there some way to make the move to the left in the paragraph?

---

EDIT:

After I added @tw16 :s answer, i added the rest of the HTML:

```
<?php for($i=1; $i<4; $i++): ?>
    <div class="formarea">
        <div class="formimg">Gäst <?php echo $i; ?>:</div>

        <div class="formtext">

            <p class="inhead">Personuppgifter:</p>

            <p class="tdone" id="namespanG<?php echo $i; ?>">Namn</p><p class="tdtwo"><input type="text" name="guest[<?php echo $i; ?>][name]" id="nameG<?php echo $i; ?>" /></p>

            <p class="inhead">Matalternativ:</p>    

            <p class="tdone">Vegetarian (vegan etc. fyll även i detta nedan)</p><p class="tdtwo"><input type="checkbox" name="guest[<?php echo $i; ?>][veg]" value="Ja" /></p>
            <p class="tdone">Allergier och andra matpreferenser</p><p class="tdtwo"><textarea name="guest[<?php echo $i; ?>][allergies]" id="allergiesG<?php echo $i; ?>"></textarea></p>

            <p class="inhead">Alkoholalternativ:</p>

            <p class="tdone">Öl</p><p class="tdtwo"><input type="radio" name="guest[<?php echo $i; ?>][drink]" value="Öl" checked /></p>
            <p class="tdone">Cider</p><p class="tdtwo"><input type="radio" name="guest[<?php echo $i; ?>][drink]" value="Cider" /></p>
            <p class="tdone">Alkoholfritt</p><p class="tdtwo"><input type="checkbox" name="guest[<?php echo $i; ?>][alcfree]" value="Ja" /></p>

        </div>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>

<div class="pbutton"><input type="submit" value="Anmäl dig" /></div>
```

The result was "interesting":

[image: Result of css]

I guess that the reason is that the "formarea"s are not filled totally, do anyone know what do do about it?

Comment: why are you not using <label> tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the alingment issues, you need to use the `clear: left` as below:

```
.inhead {
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding:0px;
    border:none;
    width:300px;
    font-size:20px;
    clear: left /* add this */
}

.tdone {
    margin-top:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    padding:0px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    clear: left /* add this */
}
```

To stop the radio and checkbox inputs from centre aligning, you need to add this rule to the end of your CSS:

```
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Can you maybe look at my edits above and see why my new parts give me new faults in the style.

Comment: No matter, i just remembered "overflow:auto;"